# Delete docker images from open shift using open shift dsl

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift, jenkins-job-dsl

How can we delete the docker images with a particular label from openshift using openshiftdsl from jenkins pipeline? Please suggest a method other than using curl, prune or using openshift oc client utility, if available.